# Can you create your own spool in symfony 2?

Tags: php, symfony, terminate, spool, symfony-http-kernel

I'm trying to **log stats after my response has been sent** in Symfony 2.

I'm using the **kernel.terminate** event but **I can't use the session** from it because **headers have been sent**. 
So I'd like to use a spool to do like SwiftMailer but with stats.

Do you know how to do that? 
Do you have other ideas on **how to pass data to the kernel.terminate event listener**? 
I looked but everything is related to Emails.

In advance thanks.